# Human verification without user action

Tags: php, user-interface, yii

For a system I'm working on I've got a bit of a problem: I'm messing with one of the basic rules of HTTP and I'm allowing users to post data through a GET request.

Don't get mad at me yet: I've got a reason for this: Users arrive in my application from an external environment and I can't prompt them for any extra input (so all necessary data is in the GET query). They should be able to close the browser window right after it opens and the input should be saved. And no, I can't do this through AJAX, an API or other under-the-hood method.

These requirements kind of rule out captcha, calculations, forms etc. So I'm left with the problem that I really do want some type of verification to prevent bots/crawlers from "accidentally" submitting something.

One of the solutions I am looking into is making a very lightweight landing page that submits itself through javascript onload but it would be the ugliest thing in my application so I'm trying to prevent it. Another is to let the landingpage not do any of the processing but instead use an AJAX-call to do this. This would however mean that older browsers (and many mobile phones) would have to use another solution.

Background: Application written in PHP5.3, built on Yii Framework, 100% cross-browser compatible (this includes pretty much every mobile phone out there).

**Some more background:** The "exteral environments" I'm talking about vary from e-mail clients to websites. Manipulation of our content at runtime isn't possible.

**Update:** Here's what I'm going to do: I'm probably going to combine solutions posted here in a fallback mechanism so that a chain of verifications will be attempted:
1. Ajax verification
2. Non-Ajax javascript verification (automatic form submission)
3. Prompt for user input (user has to click a confirm button)

Besides this I'm going to implement a bot trap as descripbed by http://www.kloth.net/internet/bottrap.php

After I'm done with building this I'll update the post if I did anything different.

Comment: So essentially what you're asking is how to determine if a specific set of data is from a human or a computer?

Comment: The last requirements of your 2nd paragraph kind of rule out your own proposed solutions in paragraph 4. brainstorming, I'd say you cannot achieve what you want with only a pure GET request coming from an 'external environment' unless you have at least some javascript running there. If you can factor in COOKIES you might already get moving farther, something in the likes of a CSRF and/or a SESSION cookie - i guess your users must be authenticated somehow.

Comment: @Alex: Yup that's pretty much it. @Stefano I'm talking about verification, not authentication.

Comment: do you have a single external environment? If so, you could profile what kind of additional data (http headers) that environment sends (or doesn't send) and use that to determine the data's validity.A simple example of this would be testing a useragent string in order to block the googlebot.

Comment: Any spec on what kind of data you're expecting and it's format? e.g. person's name, comment, phone number, address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to understand where you app is and where external environment really are. But one simple bot-removal technique I use is to put an hidden field named '**login**' or '**name**' and give it an empty value.

Human people will never fill this hidden field, but **spam bots** are always filling it. So you can discard any request with that field being not empty.

Now you must prevent **crawlers** and not only spam bots. Never did it, but here are some thoughts. You could add a hidden 'human' hidden input in the form on first mouseMove events (but keyboard-only -- and think about blind people -- users will be considered as robots). So maybe if this field is not there you can launch a javascript 'confirm' where you ask "Confirm that you are a robot or click cancel if you are human".
You can make your anchor link containing a default value that this hidden field values will overwrite in js. Most crawlers will not overwrite the values, especially if you must cancel a confirmation to get the right behavior (and avoid confirmation with mouseMove event for most users).

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to modify the place that your users are coming fro, you could try including a checksum. Calculate some kind of checksum or hash of all the fields in the GET request and add it to the GET request itself (i.e. through javascript, but do it in the place your users are coming from, not where they are landing). Then, in your application, reject all hits with an incorrect checksum.

Comment: Of course, if s/he can modify the place that users are coming from, s/he might as well change it to use POST instead of GET...

Comment: Also, I don't see how this would solve the problem. The idea is to prevent crawlers from messing with the page. If a crawler visits the page, it must have gotten the link somewhere, probably from a valid page using the system in question, and thus the crawler will probably have a valid link, including any checksum. This trick might help for crawlers that just guessed the link (if that is possible)...

Comment: @sleske: There are other reasons why GET could be used. You can't 301 redirect a POST for example. As for crawlers finding links, that's why I suggested adding the checksum to links through javascript.